# Java String.toUpperCase()

Tags: java, string, uppercase

Just the other day I ran into a strange strange bug. I had a string of characters that I had to build. And as a delimiter the host system I was communicating with used char 254. Anyway I build out my string and sent it to the host. On the host I was receiving char 222 as the delimiter! After scratching my head and looking into it deeper it seemed odd that

hex : FE, binary: 11111110

was turning into

hex: DE, binary: 11011110

I tried the Locale.getDefault() and Locale.ENGLISH to no avail.

Could it be that the implementation of String.toUpperCase has a mask for ALL chars except specific hard coded ones?

For now I'm using the following to get around the problem:

```
public static String toUpperCase(String input) {

    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();


    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i ) {

        if( chars[i] > 96 && chars[i] < 123 ) {

            chars[i] &= 223;
        }

    }

    return new String(chars);

}
```

my question is am I missing something?  Is there a better way that I am not aware of?  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java uses `UTF-16` in general.  The first 256 values of the `char` primitive type in Java are exactly the same as the Latin-1 character set, which is given [here](http://www.scism.lsbu.ac.uk/jfl/Appa/appa4.html).  On that chart you can see that capitalizing value 254 (Lower Icelandic thorn) will convert it to value 222 (Upper Icelandic thorn).

The moral is: don't use values which have case as delimiters in a String.

Comment: Thank you!  So in other words I'm the idiot not the default toUpperCase() implementer.  This makes perfect sense now that I actually know about the Icelandic sound for roughly "th" as Joni stated above.  I did not implement the host system so I had no control over what they used as delimiters.  In fact It's a very old PICK based system.  I'm marking this as the answer for the helpful link.

Answer (score 8):

The Unicode character 254 is the lower case thorn, `þ`, a letter used in Icelandic that stands roughly for the "th" sound. Its upper case version is the character 222, upper case thorn `Þ`. What did you expect would happen?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html:

> The Unicode Standard defines the default case mapping for each
>   individual character, with each character considered in isolation.
>   This mapping does not provide for the context in which the character
>   appears, nor for the language-specific rules that must be applied when
>   working in natural language text.

So it looks like the `upper/lowerCase` methods work pretty much the same way regardless of what Locale you've used.  Specifying a different Locale may affect a few specific letters (like "i" in Turkish), but it doesn't make `upper/lowerCase` stop working on entire groups of letters.  So specifying Locale.ENGLISH doesn't make `upperCase` ignore Icelandic letters--or Russian or Greek letters.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be the case that String.toUpperCase() does anything but convert to upper case in a given char set.

Your question seems to imply that the link between your system and the host is done using 8-bit character set (ASCII ?). However, Java uses 16-bit characters, in a variety of character sets (UTF-16, UTF-8, etc.) So, there must be something doing the conversion, both in interpreting the character set, and converting to 8 bit. If the character set is UTF-8, then the first 127 chars map 1-1 with ASCII. However, you are concerned with chars outside of that range, so a more complex conversion is needed. I'm guessing that is where the problem is.

So I think you should:

1. Find out what char set the host is expecting
2. Find out where the conversion from Java 16-but chars is happening. Are you doing that yourself?

I would guess that the strange behavior is somewhere in there.

Sorry I can't be more help. If you give me more details about the comm link, and the conversion process, I might be able to shed more light on what's going on

Answer (score 1):

```
Locale trlocale= Locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR");
Locale enLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("en_US");
System.out.println("üğişçö".toUpperCase(new java.util.Locale("tr", "TR")));
System.out.println("üğişçö".toUpperCase(new java.util.Locale("en", "EN")));
value = new String(value.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
```